# How to recover source code modifications accidentally closed in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, data-recovery

I edited an existing source code file in Notepad++, there were unsaved changes, but I accidentally closed the file. How can I recover it? I know the file with the unsaved changes was in `c:\Users\Tomas\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup\`. When I closed the tab in Notepad++, the file disappeared.

1. It is not present in the Recycle Bin.
2. I tried to recover the file with *EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard Free*, but it did not find it.

How can I do this? Is there any software which could do that? Or, any software to search all the sectors for some strings and return all the data around? That could be sufficient. Or is there any plugin for Notepad++?

**UPDATE:** I made a partition image of `C:` with *Macrium Reflect - Free Edition* and then searched the image file with *Total Commander Viewer* (F3) for some strings. I didn't find it. Is it possible that Notepad++ is wiping the backup data for "security" reasons? Or maybe it got overwritten on the disk so quickly?

Comment: Have you enabled "Make an exact copy of the partition" and set "compression level" to None?

Comment: @Robert yes I did :-)) It took me time to find it though. Nowadays the software is so smart it is dumb :)

Comment: If you had bad luck Windows has performed TRIM (assuming you use an SSD) before you could make the image (according to some posts the TRIM commands can be seen in Windows application event log of the "Defrag" app). BTW: I am not sure how good TC works on multi-Gigabyte images. I would recommend a tool that is optimized for reading the image using a hex editor like HxD. It can search for text if files of any size and directly visualize it.

Comment: @Robert 1) yes I have SSD, but I don't get it with the TRIM command, why would the OS rewrite the data in the unused blocks, it's not necessary; doesn't this unnecessary write just lower the lifespan of the SSD disk? 2) TC viewer worked quite well, in what regard should the HxD be better?

Comment: No the TRIM command is a special command that overwrites nothing. But blocks that are trimmed do no longer contain data. They are not connected to a flash cell anymore and thus if you try to read such a block you get only zeros as data.